# python RE: Non greedy matches, repitition and grouping

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match repeated line patterns using python RE

input_string:

start_of_line: x
line 1 
line 2 
start_of_line: y
line 1 
line 2 
line 3 
start_of_line: z
line 1

Basically I want to extract strings in a loop (each string starting from start_of_line till all characters before the next start_of_line)

I can easily solve this using a for loop, but wondering if there is a python RE to do this, tried my best but getting stuck with the grouping part.

The closest thing which resembles like a solution to me is

```
pattern= re.compile(r"start_of_line:.*?", re.DOTALL)
for match in re.findall(pattern, input_string):
    print "Match =", match
```

But it prints

```
Match = start_of_line:
Match = start_of_line:
Match = start_of_line:
```

If I do anything else to group, I lose the matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this with a regex, you must use a lookahead test:

```
r"start_of_line:.*?(?=start_of_line|$)"
```

otherwhise, since you use a lazy quantifier ( `*?` ), you will obtain the shortest match possible, i.e. nothing after `start_of_line:`

Another way:

```
r"start_of_line:(?:[^\n]+|\n(?!start_of_line:))*"
```

Here i use a character class containing all but a newline (`\n`) repeated one or more times. When the regex engine find a newline it tests if `start_of_line:` doesn't follow. I repeat the group zero or more times.

This pattern is more efficient than the first because the lookahead is performed only when a newline is encounter (vs on each characters)

Comment: you don't really need lookahead, just don't make it part of the matched group.  also you probably want `|$)`.  so: `r'start_of_line:(.*?)(?:start_of_line|$)` and then work on group 1.

Comment: @andrewcooke: good point for `|$`, but if you use groups you create an overlapping problem.

Comment: Works like a charm (without $ delimiter, the final string isn't matched), thanks for sharing your expertise.

Comment: Very good explanation of the second solution, couldn't have thought that myself ever, being a novice in RE, I will go for the first since it can be understood easily for a non-geek.